# Django REST Framework: How do you get the attributes from a serialized object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a POST method which is going to be used to retrieve a JSON object, which is then going to be used to retrieve the first_name, last_name, and username -- although I can't figure out how to get the fields (i.e. username) after I serialize it. What's the best way to go about that?

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createUser(request):
    # Making a Connection w/ MongoClient
    client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://test_user:0FP33TLJVWrjl8Vy@cluster0.5sacp.mongodb.net/sample_clubs?retryWrites=true&w=majority')

    # Getting the Database
    db = client['sample_clubs']

    # Getting the Collection/Table
    collection = db['users']
    serializer = MyUserSerializer(data=request.data)

    # Gives bug if next 2 lines aren't here
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def get_first_name(self, obj):
        # obj is model instance
        return obj.first_name

    def get_last_name(self, obj):
        # obj is model instance
        return obj.last_name
    
    def get_user_name(self, obj):
        # obj is model instance
        return obj.user_name

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username']
        # fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: What is the issue with current setup?

Comment: You want the username after you called `serializer.save()` to see what username has been saved? or want the raw serialized data?

Comment: Currently I can't figure out what to pass into the obj argument of the get functions or if they work. I found the idea for the implementation in another StackOverflow question, however I was unable to find the documentation for it and got stuck on how to proceed with calling the get functions and getting the native Python strings to parse.

Comment: @NavidZarepak I'd like to get the username as a string after that (I can't remove those 2 lines or I'd get an error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A serializer's `save` method in DRF will return the instance that has been saved. So you can simply call any of its field like this:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    obj = serializer.save()
    print(obj.user_name)
```

The data will also be available through the serializer's validated data:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    print(serializer.validated_data.get('user_name')
```

You can also use the raw JSON that's been generated by serializer:

```
# note that serializer.data won't be available if 'is_valid()` returns False
print(serializer.data["user_name"])
```

Also, you shouldn't return `serializer.data` outside of the `is_valid` scope. If `is_valid()` is `False`, then there won't be any data so you will run to an error. The proper way would be this:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
return Response(serializer.errors)
```

If you only want to return the `user_name` as response:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    obj = serializer.save()
    return Response({"username": obj.user_name})
return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Comment: Thanks so much this fixed my problem!